# Identifying trends in mutually exclusive categorical variables

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data

I'm posting here as I'm not even sure where to start Googling. Say I have a system that can be in one of three states – A, B, or C –  and *only* one of these states when observed, which I do annually. A time series of such observation might look like this:

```
# Seed RNG
set.seed(33550336)

# Define data frame
df <- data.frame(year = 1990:2010, state = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 21, replace = TRUE))

# Plot results
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = year, y = 1, fill = state)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("")
```

[image]

If I was looking at numeric data, my first exploration tool looking for trends may be plotting the data over time, then fitting a simple linear model. I'm not sure what the equivalent is here for mutually exclusive categorical data. I could consider a particular state – A, for instance – and take a running mean of whether the system is in this state (`TRUE`) or not in this state (`FALSE`).

```
df %<>%
  mutate(state_A = ifelse(state == "A", TRUE, FALSE),
         rollmean = rollmean(state_A, k = 3, fill = NA))

# Plot results
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = rollmean)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Rolling mean")
```

[image]

Okay, so there seems to be a trend, but this seems to be neglecting important information, since A, B, and C are all interrelated. I expect that there is an abundance of literature on analysing such data, so can someone suggest a foothold where I can get started? What would be the first analysis you do when working with these data?